# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32gui: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, runtime-error, pyinstaller, pywin32, win32gui

i am using win32gui libaray and the code runs in the Python environment without any problems but when I get the exe output with pyinstaller and execute it
Such an error will be displayed: **ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32gui: The specified module could not be found.**
I uninstalled the pywin32 library and reinstalled it, but the problem was not solved.
Import Code:

```
import win32.win32gui
```

Comment: What about simply `import win32gui`?

Comment: It did not solve the problem